# Can't understand this vector declaration

Tags: c++

I'm a real noob in C++ and I've a very simple question.

```
vector<int> s[10];
```

What does this declaration actually do? Is s a vector with capacity for 10 integers? What's the difference comparing to this:

```
vector<int> s(10);
```

I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question, but I really can't understand what this declarations do.

Thanks!

Comment: It's an array of 10 vectors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is an array of 10 empty vectors.

The second one is a single vector initialised with 10 elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mix of std::vector and built-in array types. Specifically an array of `std::vector`;

```
vector<int> s[10];
```

means create 10 vector objects. You can think of it like:

```
vector<int> s0;
vector<int> s1;
...
vector<int> s10;
```

The number of vector objects is fixed. The number of items in each vector can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Vector has a constructor like this:

```
vector (size_type n);
```

So the second is just declare a vector of int with size of 10.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> s[10];`Means "s" is a array, and it have 10 elements, each of its element's type is `vector<int>`.

`vector<int> s(10);`Means "s" is a `vector<int>`, and this vector's size is 10, but this is not a declaration.

There can be much more complex declarations, when declare a function pointer which point to the kind function who have a lot of parameters and complex return value.

For example:

`vector<int> (*func[10])(int *);`
This declare the pointer point to a function who receive `int *` parameter, and return a`vector<int>` value, plus it is an array of this kind pointer, the size of the array is 10.